# How to troubleshoot job failures in ssis?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

All I want to learn is how to atleast debug if not resolve job failures in ssis 2005. I want to know how can I learn all this as I have a basic knowledge of SSIS and sql.

Any guidance is welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS is divided into “control flow” and “data flow”
On the control flow you can use breakpoints as you do on your c# application for example. Just right click a task and select “add breakpoint”. There are several options, all of them are self explicatory (like before action, after action and so on)
On the data flow,  you can’t use breakpoints, you have to use data viewers. Data viewers display data between two components in a data flow, you can add a grid between your oledbsource and your oledbdestination and see the data passing through.

Links:

- Debugging Control Flow - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140274(v=sql.90).aspx
- Debugging Data Flow - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137944(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

One thing that helps tremendously is to log each step of your package (and have an error handler to log errors), then you can look through the logs to see exactly what worked and where it failed.